# Python: 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import module from another coding .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.8.3 on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

I'm currently building an online chat and this is my person.py code:

```
class Person:

    """
    Represents a person, hold name, socket client and client addr
    """
    def __init__(self, addr, client):
        self.addr = addr
        self.client = client
        self.name = None

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Person({self.addr}, {self.name})"
```

And this is my server.py coding:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
from person import Person

# GLOBAL CONSTANTS
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5500
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10
BUFSIZ = 512

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
persons = []
SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)  # set up server

def broadcast(msg, name):
    """
    send new messages to all clients
    :param msg: bytes["utf8"]
    :param name: str
    :return:
    """
    for person in persons:
        client = person.client
        client.send(bytes(name, "utf8") + msg)


def client_communication(person):
    """
    Thread to handle all messages from client
    :param person: Person
    :return: None
    """
    client = person.client

    # get persons name
    name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    person.set_name(name)
    msg = bytes(f"{name} has joined the chat!", "utf8")
    broadcast(msg, "")  # broadcast welcome message


    while True:
        try:
            msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ)

            if msg == bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
                client.close()
                persons.remove(person)
                broadcast(f"{name} has left the chat...", "")
                print(f"[DISCONNECTED] {name} disconnected")
                break
            else:
                broadcast(msg, name+": ")
                print(f"{name}: ", msg.decode("utf8"))

        except Exception as e:
            print("[EXCEPTION]", e)
            break


def wait_for_connection():
    """
    Wait for connetion from new clients, start new thread once connected
    :param SERVER: SOCKET
    :return: None
    """
    run = True
    while run:
        try:
            client, addr = SERVER.accept()
            person = Person(addr, client)
            persons.append(person)
            print(f"[CONNECTION] {addr} connected to the server at {time.time()}")
            Thread(target=client_communication, args=(person,)).start()
        except Exception as e:
            print("[EXCEPTION]", e)
            run = False

    print("SERVER CRASHED")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER.listen(MAX_CONNECTIONS)  # listen for connections
    print("[STARTED] Waiting for connections...")
    ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=wait_for_connection)
    ACCEPT_THREAD.start()
    ACCEPT_THREAD.join()
    SERVER.close()
```

The problem is, everytime i try to run the program, it gives me this error:

```
    from person import Person
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'person'
```

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is `person` on your Python path? How precisely are your running your code?

Comment: This is an importing issue. You need to provide details of the location of both files.

Comment: 1-how do i see if it is on my python path? 2- im running it using my python console. is it precisely?

Comment: how do i provide the details?

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

Most likely, this is a path-finding error. The Python Path will look in the installation's `lib` and `site-packages` folders. It will also look at the current working directory. So if you're running one file from another folder but trying to import something it will look in your running directory instead of where the file you're running. Here are two solutions to this problem.

#### First Solution

You can make the working directory the same as the file you're running. Giving the following file structure:

```
workingdir
+-- thecode
    |-- server.py
    +-- person.py
```

You have the current working directory aka where you're running your command as `workingdir` so a terminal might look like this:

```
workingdir % python thecode/server.py
```

Thus you need to change the working directory to `thecode` instead. Do `cd thecode` to get there.

#### Second Solution

You can instead add the file's directory to the python path. This is held in sys.path, and gets at the end of each python run. Thus, it is best to add to the path at the beginning of your `server.py` file so that `person.py` is in your path before you import it. Use something like the following code to do this.

```py
import sys
import os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0])

# now you may import Person.
from person import Person
```

The first two modules, `sys` and `os`, are pretty standard and will give you the tools to append to the Python path. The `os.path.abspath` gets the absolute path of your current file, in this case it's `server.py`. Then `os.path.split` will get the trailing (all the directories) and the head (the filename) of your absolute path. Finally appending to the `sys.path` allows Python to find `person.py` in your file's directory.

#### Other Solutions (That probably won't be used in this case)

You can also create a custom Python package and install it using `pip`. This isn't very useful in this case since the import problem is just one file, however, if you ever want to create a custom Python project that other's may use [this Python docs article will help](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

The final solution (which admittedly I used to do and isn't the best workaround) is to put your file in a folder that's already in the Python path. In this case, it would probably be the `lib` folder. For me, running Python 3.8 the path is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8`, for any Python 3.x version this will be the same but the version replaced. Python 2.x has different locations sometimes.